# error: Unexpected error: Illegal name .$HelloControllerDefinition

Tags: micronaut

I have followed the Getting Started. First start of Application was Ok. Then I added a Controller as described (HelloController.java in src/main/java/helloworld. When I restart the server, I get the following error:

```
c:\dev\micronaut\helloworld>gradlew run
```

> Task :compileJava FAILED
>   Note: Creating bean classes for 1 type elements
>   error: Unexpected error: Illegal name .$HelloControllerDefinition
>   1 error

I am under Windows 10 with jdk 1.8_171

Comment: Could you include the actual code you have written.

Comment: From the looks up the error it seems your HelloController doesn't define a package, but if you provide more information maybe we can help

Answer (score 5):

As Graeme Rocher mentioned, the class is missing it's `package`. If you add the line I've added below, it should work.

```
package helloworld;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;

@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @Get
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: I should also mention that the tutorial states to create this file in:
`src/main/java/example/helloworld/HelloController.java`
whereas it should be in:
`src/main/java/helloworld/HelloController.java`

Further, at least on Windows 10, it seems that running:
`mn create-app hello-world`
results in a folder structure like:
`src/main/java/hello/world/HelloController.java`

So I ran:
`mn create-app helloworld`

Comment: I think this should be added to the getting started documentation. Otherwise you get stuck there and forget about Micronaut.