# Micronaut HelloWorld Error: Unexpected error: Illegal name .$HelloControllerDefinition

Tags: micronaut

**Trying to proceed the demo code on** https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#creatingServer

**with the step following：**
src/main/java/example/helloworld/HelloController.java

**came the error:**

```js
> Task :compileJava FAILED
Note: Creating bean classes for 1 type elements
error: Unexpected error: Illegal name .$HelloControllerDefinition
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

**i knew there was another question related this but has no answer**
[error: Unexpected error: Illegal name .$HelloControllerDefinition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057886/error-unexpected-error-illegal-name-hellocontrollerdefinition)

what should i do?

**and the hellocontroller is exactly as the doc tells as follow**

```js
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;

@Controller("/hello") 
public class HelloController {
    @Get 
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your HelloController.java file look like?

Comment: exactly as the demo tells as above. i've edited my question and add the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HelloController` needs to be defined to be in a package. If you followed the guide exactly, try the following,

```js
package example.helloworld;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;

@Controller("/hello") 
public class HelloController {
    @Get 
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: problem solved. thanks a lot.ps.but in the official doc ,really doesn't has this line.

Comment: +1000 to last comment.  I was trying out micronaut just to see if maybe it might be worth learning, and almost stopped at this point because it failed my '5 minute test'  -- If some products very first demo app as documented fails to run as-is -- that's usually an indicator of many more problems to come.